# Why do my headphones hiss when I plug them into my iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, headphones

When I plug in my headphones to my iPod touch (first gen), I get a weird hissing noise that I don't get when I plug them into anything else. Also, If I plug different headphones into the iPod, no hissing noise.

Is this interference? Or another problem?

Aside from getting new headphones or getting a new iPod touch, what are my options?

Comment: What happens when you plug the hissy headphones into anything else? Also, do the hissy headphones have three or four sections of contact on the plug?

Comment: I think it's easier to ask them how many rings their plug has.

Comment: There are three connectors on the headphones plug.

Comment: Also, if i plug them into anything else they are fine

Comment: I'm sorry, two connectors on the headphones

Answer (score 1):

The iPod touches (and most recent iPods, dating back to the 6th gen original iPod) have four contacts to allow stereo audio as well as the microphone and inline controls. (This uses a TRRS [tip-ring-ring-sleeve] plug instead of a TRS [tip-ring-sleeve] plug as usually seen on stereo headphones. More info at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector).)

Your headphones, since you said there were three connectors, are almost certainly TRS. If you can shine a flashlight into the headphone hole, there might be a bent pin in there that is causing a poor connection or a connection to the wrong segment. The only way I can think of to fix this, however, is to try to shove it around with a paperclip or other stiff wire.